# Model formulation of mixed models: from R (nlme and gamm) syntax to mathematical

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, lme4-nlme, mgcv

I have finalized two types of models, a linear mixed effects model and a generalized additive model for my data set. I have read and understood how it works and how to choose which model would be the best fit. However, now I am writing a paper and I have to report the model in a mathematical way and I am not sure if I am doing it right. How can I understand the model without going into math so much?

To give you an overview of my design, I want to determine the change in cell density on my observation area with response to treatment over time. I further divided my observation area into 3 concentric rings that I called bins. For each treatment, I have also 3 replicates. I decided to test models and found out that the optimum model would be:

```
CellCount ~ treatment*time*bin, random= ~1|replicate,
weights=varIdent(form=~1|replicate), correlation=corAR1(form=~1|replicate/treatment)
```

In a mathematical context:

\begin{align}
{\rm Count} =\  &\beta_0 + \beta_1 {\rm treatment}_j + \beta_2 {\rm bin}_j + \beta_3 {\rm time}_t + \beta_4 {\rm treatment}_j\ {\rm bin}_j +  \\
              &\beta_5 {\rm treatment}_j\ {\rm time}_t + \beta_6 {\rm bin}_j\ {\rm time} + \beta_7 {\rm treatment}_j\ {\rm bin}_j\ {\rm time}_t +  \\
              &b_1 {\rm replicate} + \varepsilon_{ij}
\end{align}

For GAMM, its also the same design but this time, I have speed as my response variable which does not increase linearly over time so that is why I did not use LME.

```
Speed ~  s(time, by=treatment, bs="fs", xt="cr") + 
         s(bin, by=treatment, bs="fs", xt="cr") + 
         ti(time, bin, by=treatment, bs="fs", xt="cr"), 
         correlation = corAR1 (form = ~ 1|bin/ID), random=list(ID=~1), 
         weights= varIdent(form= ~1|treatment)
```

I have no idea how to write the formula for this one. I know the idea about smoothers and tensor interactions though.

Comment: Separately from any mathematical concerns, I'd recommend looking at the reporting standards of the journal(s) you are planning on submitting the manuscript to. That is, look at how other papers published in that journal report their models, especially those using similar models. Depending on the details of your paper and the journal (and the field/discipline you are involved in), you may not need to explicitly and algebraically define the model. In many contexts, simply reporting the type of model you are using (i.e. mixed effects) and the variables under consideration is sufficient.

Comment: As a follow-up to my last comment, let me continue by saying that for your own benefit in understanding the model it is probably still beneficial to work out the algebraic definition. I only mean to say that it may not be necessary for the manuscript in and of itself, especially since you profess to understanding the model in a general sense.

Comment: @Ryan Simmons, yup I lookes that up and they need an algebraic formula but it would really be nice on my side to learn it, like you said! :)